# Google deprecation notice for OAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console

I got this mail from google a few months ago, there is some page that describing this deprecation?

Does September 13 is really the last day I can use "HTTP" schema in my services with google javascript OAuth ?

The mail:

> Hello Google Developer,
>
> We are writing to let you know that you have active OAuth redirect
> URIs and JavaScript origins in your Google Cloud project that are not
> in compliance with Google’s OAuth URI validation rules. All
> noncompliant active URIs will be removed, along with their origins, by
> September 13, 2021.
>
> What do I need to do to be compliant? Please update your app and OAuth
> configuration in the Google Developer Console to use redirect URIs or
> JavaScript origins that are compliant with the OAuth URI validation
> rules by September 13, 2021.
>
> The following Google Cloud project(s), which has/have registered URIs
> and origins that are out of compliance, and which will be removed if
> you do not update your OAuth flow to use compliant redirect URIs and
> Javascript origins by September 13, 2021:
>
> Project ID: ************************ (DELETED) Client:
> ************************ (DELETED) URI: http://************************ (DELETED) URI:
> http://************************ (DELETED) URI:
> http://************************ (DELETED) If you have any questions or
> concerns regarding these changes, please review the documentation
> provided above in this email.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Google Developer Team

Answer (score 1):

So far so good, google didn't delete old "http://" websites from OAuth.